# How to solve an inequality using low precision (< MachinePrecision)?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, precision-and-accuracy, inequalities

I would like to use low precision data (based on measurement results with a low precision) to solve a set of inequalities. I have prepared a minimum working example to demonstrate the issue. I am using Mathematica version `11.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)`.

Let's start with an equation:

```
eq = 0.013455``7*x == 2.455``4;
{#, InputForm[#]} &@ (x /. Solve[eq, x][[1]])

(* {182.5,182.4600520252694165677`4.089021500795006} *)
```

The result has a precision of approx. 4 digits. The input equation (fixed `Accuracy`) is converted to a fixed `Precision` expression:

```
InputForm @ eq

(* 0.013455`5.128883702099774*x == 2.455`4.390051496458987 *)
```

My real word problem is an inequality (more precisely: a set of inequalities, but let's keep it simple for this demonstration). `Solve` is not able to find a solution now:

```
Solve[eq /. Equal -> LessEqual, x]

(*
Solve::fulldim: The solution set contains a full-dimensional component; use Reduce for complete solution information.
Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.

{{}}
*)
```

If I use `Reduce`, I get a solution, but the precision is much larger than expected (i.e., a precision of approximately 16 which is even greater than $MachinePrecision):

```
{#, InputForm[#]} &@ (Reduce[eq /. Equal -> LessEqual, x])

(*
Reduce::ratnz: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.

{x <= 182.4591071428571,x <= 182.45910714285714285714285714285714285714`16.255619765854984}
*)
```

How can I solve the inequality (either with `Solve` or `Reduce`) with correct precision? We should expect:

```
x <= 182.4600520252694165677`4.089021500795006
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you introduce "slack" variables to represent the uncertainties in your data and then replace your inexact values with exact ones?

Comment: I have tried this approach with two slack variables `eq = SetPrecision[(0.013455 + e1)*x <= (2.455 + e2),
   MachinePrecision + 1]` (I had to exceed MachinePrecision first to get it work). Afterwards, `Reduce[eq, x, Reals] /. {e1 -> SetAccuracy[0., 7], e2 -> SetAccuracy[0., 4]}` gave me a low precision answer. I would prefer a solution without slack variables.

Comment: by the way: Mathematica version `11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)` has the same issue

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval) objects instead of reals. In your example, I would first apply [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval) to your low precision number:

```
Interval[0.013455``7] //InputForm
```

> Interval[{0.0134548807907104492`5.128879854298511, 0.0134551192092895508`5.1288875498669455}]

and then convert the end points of the interval into machine precision:

```
Interval[0.013455``7] //N
```

> Interval[{0.0134549, 0.0134551}]

So, for your equation, we have:

```
eq = 0.013455``7*x == 2.455``4;
ieq = eq /. r_Real :> N @ Interval[r]
```

> x Interval[{0.0134549, 0.0134551}] == Interval[{2.45488, 2.45512}]

Then, you can use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) as usual (I included a domain restriction because is avoids some error messages later):

```
Solve[ieq, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> Interval[{182.449, 182.471}]}}

For the inequality:

```
leq = LessEqual @@ ieq;
```

[`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) again doesn't work:

```
Solve[leq, x, Reals]
```

> Solve::fdimc: When parameter values satisfy the condition True, the solution set contains a full-dimensional component; use Reduce for complete solution information.
>
> {}

But this time [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) works fine:

```
Reduce[leq, x, Reals]
```

> x <= Interval[{182.449, 182.471}]